# Why echoing JSON encoded arrays won't produce any output

Tags: php, json

I've a little DB with 19elements, that's my PHP function to retrieve the DB:

```
function retrieveDB(){

    $tempDB=array();

    $database=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){ 
        echo "Errore in connessione al database: ".mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    $query="SELECT * FROM dr ORDER BY indice;";
    $risultato=$database->query($query);

    while($row = $risultato->fetch_assoc()){

        $tempDB[]=$row;
    }

    $database->close();
    return $tempDB;
}
```

I tried both

```
$temp=retrieveDB();
echo json_encode($temp);
```

and

```
foreach($temp as $t){
echo json_encode($t);}
```

but it seems to print only 3 elements on 19, skipping the others. That's my output:

```
{"indice":"1","domanda":"Quale principio attivo fa passare quel brutto mal di vivere?","risposta":"PARACETAMOLO","visibile":"1"}


{"indice":"4","domanda":"SARTANO utilizzato nella profilassi dell'ictus?","risposta":"LOSARTAN","visibile":"1"}













{"indice":"18","domanda":"Quale farmaco aumenta la concentrazione ematica della digossina? ","risposta":"VERAPAMIL","visibile":"1"}
```

I also encoded values in utf8. Any advices?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't over writing `$tempDB` with every pass of that loop? Try printing the values you get from there (inside the loop instead of afterwards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings you retrieve from the database are not encoded as UTF-8 (they are ISO-8859-1, I presume). This is why `json_encode()` fails. It triggers a warning that says `json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument` but your setup probably does not allow PHP display the errors.

Put `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` somewhere on top of your script and you'll see them.

Comment: Well i did it but it doesn't print anything... By the way, i thought too that was an utf8 problem but dunno how to solve it. I've encoded data submitted to the DB, encoded the data retrieved too and the DB has utf8_general_ci character set. I feel like wandering in open sea...

Comment: Add a `var_dump($t);` before `echo` and check what data come from the database. Choose an entry that is not handled by the `json_encode()` and contains accented letters. Compare the number of characters you see in the string with the string size reported by `var_dump()`. If they **match** then your string is not encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes) says: "In the event of a failure to encode, `json_last_error()` can be used to determine the exact nature of the error."

Comment: Did it, the error code is 5 alias bad utf encode. Now i've encoded values before sending them to json_encode but the accented letters or the ' are completely messed up, is there a way to insert accented letters and ' into a json_encode? Or i'm not able to send data from my db to jS?

Comment: You can use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the encoding of the data that come from the database to `UTF-8` before `json_encode()` it.

Comment: Nope, still not working. accented letters are all messed up like  '\u00e8' as 'è'. What's the best practise to avoid this problem? I have to mb_convert input data BEFORE insert them into database? Because, i think, the problem is in the DB. Otherwise, those functions are all bugged xD

Comment: They are not messed up at all. `\u00e8` is [the character at position 0xe8 in the Unicode set](http://codepoints.net/U+00E8) (`0xe8` is 232 in decimal). And that character is exactly `è`. `json_encode()` produces a text representation of the data that uses only ASCII printable characters (having their codes between 32 and 126, I think). This is how `JSON` works and I'm absolutely sure you can decode it and use it without problems in Javascript.

Comment: Axiac i thank you so much for your answers and really appreciate your effort but I can only imagine 2 ways to decode my informations:1) use jQuery.parseJSON, but it only splits the string in n id:value pairs; 2) create a custom function to substitute those substring with the correct character. I'm sure there are a lot of ways but I just don't figure out how to do it.