# Code Works on Server not on Xampp: json_encode

Tags: php, json, xampp

Hi I have a piece of code which works on my uberspace server but doesn't work on xampp (mac).

The code is basically a  database request:

```
get_all_experts($errors, $rows, ' WHERE active < CURDATE() AND active IS NOT null');
echo count($rows);//Is 14 in the example
echo json_encode($rows);//Doesn't return anything 
$arr = array (1,'b'=>'2','c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);//works

function get_all_experts(&$errors, &$rows, $selector)
{
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM experts'.$selector);
  if (!$result) {
    $errors['sql_experts'] = 'Kein Ergebnis: '.mysql_error();
  }
  else {
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
        get_expert_tags($errors, $rows, $r);
        get_last_expert_experience($errors, $rows, $r);        
        }

  }
};
```

The two inner functions just do database requests as well and add nested values. E.g. 1 expert has more than one experience.

EDIT:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'blub', 'mySecretPassword') or exit(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('blab', $conn) or exit(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What errors are you getting? Have you figured out what line the error is happening on?

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't show any error it just tells me "No Properties" (in the preview tab of the network)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27316555/4265352). I think its the same problem.

Comment: Thx, that's the problem. My table should be utf-8 but there is a message configuration cache disabled maybe that prevents it from using my settings. Now I just have to find out how to solve that.