# json_encode doesn't get echo'ed

Tags: php, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to pull some records from the DB with the code below, but my `echo json_encode($contacts);` at the end of the code doesn't print anything. Nor does any `echo` put right above that.

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectionInfo.php');


    //Set up our connection
    $connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    $connectionInfo->GetConnection();

    if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
    {
        //Connection failed
        echo 'No Connection';
    }

    else
    {
        //Create query to retrieve all contacts
        $query = 'SELECT Numero_Leccion,Titulo_Leccion,Ejemplo_Leccion FROM leccion';

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

        if (!$stmt)
        {
            //Query failed
            echo 'Query failed';
        }

        else
        {
            $contacts = array(); //Create an array to hold all of the contacts
            //Query successful, begin putting each contact into an array of contacts

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //While there are still contacts
            {
                //Create an associative array to hold the current contact
                //the names must match exactly the property names in the contact class in our C# code.
                $contact = array("Numero_Leccion"=>$row['Numero_Leccion'],"Titulo_Leccion"=>$row['Titulo_Leccion'],"Ejemplo_Leccion"=>$row['Ejemplo_Leccion']);              
                //Add the contact to the contacts array
                array_push($contacts, $contact);
            }
            //Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
            echo json_encode($contacts);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: And your question is? It outputs nothing, or `NULL`, or ..?

Comment: it echos nothing if i place and regular echo above the echo json_encode($contatcts) if gets there. and the output gets blank. another thing if i echo this "echo json_encode($contact)" it does print that array

Comment: my query actually retrieves 4 records from the database and my code doesnt echo it back.

Comment: added an actual question (see comments), changed title a bit

Answer (score 0):

Put `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` somewhere on top of your script and see if there are any errors

(taken from [Why echoing JSON encoded arrays won't produce any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316555/why-echoing-json-encoded-arrays-wont-produce-any-output?rq=1))

Comment: nop no error, everything look if i echo json_encode($contacts); echos nothing if i instead do this echo json_encode($contact); like just one array at a time it echos the last 3 records that i want on json format but with contacts doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $contacts[] = array("Numero_Leccion"=>$row['Numero_Leccion'],"Titulo_Leccion"=>$row['Titulo_Leccion'],"Ejemplo_Leccion"=>$row['Ejemplo_Leccion']);              
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($contacts);
```

Comment: it looked like a problem on the tables on sql i created a fresh one like exactly like the one i had and it worked i don t know why...